# Error binding table-valued parameter while using ODBC, c++

Tags: c++, odbc

I am attempting to pass a table-valued parameter as a parameter in a stored procedure using ODBC. I have followed examples from MSDN, but receive the following error when I call **SQLBindParameter**:

> HY004
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid SQL data type

Here is my code.

```
//Allocate stament handle
SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hDbc, &hStmt);

//Prep command
SQLPrepare(hStmt, (SQLCHAR*)"{call myStoredProc(?)}", SQL_NTS)

//Variables
const int arraySize = 2;
const int varcharSize = 30;
SQLCHAR *myUserDefTableName = (SQLCHAR *) "myUserDefTableName";
SQLLEN     myUserDefTableInd = 0;



//bind table item

int result = SQLBindParameter(hStmt, 
  1,// ParameterNumber
  SQL_PARAM_INPUT,// InputOutputType
  SQL_C_DEFAULT,// ValueType 
  SQL_SS_TABLE,// Parametertype
  (SQLINTEGER)arraySize,// ColumnSize - for a TVP this the row array size
  0,// DecimalDigits - for a TVP this is the number of columns in the TVP 
  (SQLPOINTER)myUserDefTableName,// ParameterValuePtr - for a TVP this is       the type name of the TVP
  SQL_NTS,// BufferLength - for a TVP this is the length of the type name or SQL_NTS
  &myUserDefTableInd);// StrLen_or_IndPtr - for a TVP this is the number of rows available

//bind columns for the table-valued parameter 
//and execute command
...
```

I've also found this on MSDN:

> A table-valued parameter column cannot be bound as type SQL_SS_TABLE. If SQLBindParameter is called with ParameterType set to SQL_SS_TABLE, SQL_ERROR is returned and a diagnostic record is generated with SQLSTATE=HY004, "Invalid SQL data type". This can also occur with SQLSetDescField and SQLSetDescRec.

But I am trying to bind the table item, not the table columns. This almost seems to directly contradict what is stated in their code examples. I am unsure as to why this error occurs. Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you have ODBC set to version 3.x? Try this right after the call to get the statement handle:

```
 SQLHENV  hEnv  = SQL_NULL_HENV;
 SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &hEnv); 

 SQLSetEnvAttr(hEnv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION,(SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, SQL_IS_INTEGER);
```

Answer (score 1):

The call to **SQLBindParameter** can also fail with "Invalid SQL data type" when the **SQL Data Type**, `SQL_SS_TABLE` in this case, is unknown to the **ODBC Driver** you're using.

You can check the installed ODBC drivers and their versions by opening the **ODBC Data Source Administrator** under the **Drivers** tab:

[image: Win7 ODBC Drivers]

I was using the default "SQL Server" driver, as specified in the connection string passed to **SQLDriverConnect**.

```
SQLDriverConnect(hdbc, NULL, (SQLCHAR*)"DRIVER={SQL Server}...
```

However, this driver is from 2010 and does not appear to support the `SQL_SS_TABLE` SQL Type. *Hence the SQLBindParameter call issues the invalid type error record*. Changing this driver to `SQL Server Native Client 11.0` resolved the issue for me, as that one is from 2016 and most likely more up-to-date.

```
SQLDriverConnect(hdbc, NULL, (SQLCHAR*)"DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}...
```

Updating the default "SQL Server" driver to a later version or using a later operating system will most likely solve the issue as well or not cause it in the first place.